# Replacement for "Or" to avoid twice evaluation of conditions and to improve query performace

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, sql-server-2008, operators

"Or" decreases the performance of query because the optimizer has to evaluate both the conditions. In complex queries this becomes very expensive to evaluate two conditions because of joins and heavy tables. So what are replacements for "Or" operator. Do we use UNION every time? Then what about running the same complex query twice? And on the contrary it's also expensive.

**Edit:**

In the below example six tables are used and they all have more that 100000 records in each. The **Or** operator is between **ccm.cID = 1001** and **(ma.coID = 2 AND ma.cID = 1001)**. And to fetch records the optimizer has to evaluate both the conditions. :

```
SELECT dep.*
FROM dep with (NOLOCK)
JOIN ma with (NOLOCK) ON dep.mID = ma.mID  
LEFT JOIN ccm with (NOLOCK) ON ccm.cID = dep.cID  
LEFT JOIN ctm with (NOLOCK) ON ctm.cID = dep.cID  
LEFT JOIN cptgm with (NOLOCK) ON cptgm.cID = dep.cID  
WHERE ma.mtID = 3
AND dep.del = 0 AND dep.pub = 1   
AND (ccm.cID = 1001 OR (ma.coID = 2 AND ma.cID = 1001))  
AND ctm.tID = 2  
AND cptgm.ptgID IN (SELECT ptgID FROM psptgm WHERE psID = 145214
AND ib = 1)
```

And if we break the query in two with having one condition at time and then combine it with a **UNION** the performance decreases because of the twice execution.

Comment: Make a concrete example. As it stands, your question seems to make little sense.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth: Example Added.

Answer (score 1):

Not a lot you can do without knowing more about or changing the data model

Lets take it step by step and find a small optimization in this example:

First pull out the sub-query to a join, I believe this change will give you better performance on some version of SQL.  Also it makes the query clearer.

```
SELECT dep.*
FROM dep with (NOLOCK)
JOIN ma with (NOLOCK) ON dep.mID = ma.mID  
LEFT JOIN ccm with (NOLOCK) ON ccm.cID = dep.cID  
LEFT JOIN ctm with (NOLOCK) ON ctm.cID = dep.cID  
LEFT JOIN cptgm with (NOLOCK) ON cptgm.cID = dep.cID  
JOIN psptgm with (NOLOCK) ON cptgm.ptgID = psptgm.ptgID and psptgm.ib = 1 and psptgm.psID = 145214
WHERE ma.mtID = 3
  AND dep.del = 0 
  AND dep.pub = 1   
  AND (ccm.cID = 1001 OR (ma.coID = 2 AND ma.cID = 1001))  
  AND ctm.tID = 2
```

I also prefer to write it like this (I think it is clearer):

```
SELECT dep.*
FROM dep with (NOLOCK)
JOIN ma with (NOLOCK) ON dep.mID = ma.mID and  ma.mtID = 3
LEFT JOIN ccm with (NOLOCK) ON ccm.cID = dep.cID  
LEFT JOIN ctm with (NOLOCK) ON ctm.cID = dep.cID AND ctm.tID = 2
LEFT JOIN cptgm with (NOLOCK) ON cptgm.cID = dep.cID  
JOIN psptgm with (NOLOCK) ON cptgm.ptgID = psptgm.ptgID and psptgm.ib = 1 and psptgm.psID = 145214
WHERE dep.del = 0 
  AND dep.pub = 1   
  AND (ccm.cID = 1001 OR (ma.coID = 2 AND ma.cID = 1001))
```

This makes the join only modifiers vs the where clause clearer.

Now It is easy to see the common parts of the or in the main select and pull those out  (thus reducing the number of checks the or clause makes and increasing performance):

```
WITH prequery AS
(
  SELECT dep.*
  FROM dep with (NOLOCK)
  LEFT JOIN ctm with (NOLOCK) ON ctm.cID = dep.cID AND ctm.tID = 2
  LEFT JOIN cptgm with (NOLOCK) ON cptgm.cID = dep.cID  
  JOIN psptgm with (NOLOCK) ON cptgm.ptgID = psptgm.ptgID and psptgm.ib = 1 and psptgm.psID = 145214
  WHERE dep.del = 0 AND dep.pub = 1
)
SELECT dep.*
FROM prequery with (NOLOCK)
JOIN ma with (NOLOCK) ON dep.mID = ma.mID and  ma.mtID = 3
LEFT JOIN ccm with (NOLOCK) ON ccm.cID = dep.cID  
LEFT JOIN cptgm with (NOLOCK) ON cptgm.cID = dep.cID  
WHERE ISNULL(ccm.cID,0) = 1001 OR (ma.coID = 2 AND ma.cID = 1001)
```

Comment: +1 for the last query. Also I think you have to change LEFT JOIN to INNER JOIN when connecting tables `ctm` and `cptgm` as soon as conditions in WHERE don't allow NULLs for these tables.

Comment: @valex you are right, it needs a coalesce